# How to display a list into Flask select?

Tags: python, flask

I have created a function with two list and want to display it in a `seq.html` file.

```
@app.route('/datasets/<dataset>/sequentialprocess', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def sequential_process(dataset=dataset):
    models = request.form.get('models')
    strategy = request.form.get('strategy')

    strategies = ['MEI (exploit)', 'MU (explore)', 'MLI (exploit & explore)', 'MEID (exploit)', 'MLID (explore & exploit)']
     mdl = ['Gaussian Process Regression (GPR)', 'lolo Random Forrest (RF)', 'Decision Trees (DT)', 'Random Forrest (RFscikit)']

     return render_template('seq.html', strategies=strategies, mdl=mdl)
```

Here is my one of the list using `jinja` in `seq.html`:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <h7>Strategy:</h7>
    <select name="strategy" class="form-control is-valid" required>
        {% for st in strategies %}
          <option value="{{st}}">{{st}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

But the list `strategies` not display in `seq.html`. Can someone tell me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your HTML. You are missing some HTML tags.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <h7>Strategy:</h7>
      <select name="strategy" class="form-control is-valid" required>
          {% for st in strategies %}
            <option value="{{st}}">{{st}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
      </select>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HTML tags are there I did not include in here.

Comment: I ran the code and It works correctly on my end. If you have the tags, then the problem is not with this piece of code.